# Is there a way to sort posts by taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, order

I was wondering if I could sort posts at all by taxonomy terms?  I've read that I can't, but I'm not too sure about that?

If so, how do I go about doing so?

Sorry for the rather short question.  I have made several topics over the last week regarding this question and all were very detailed and elaborate but I've yet to get a single response.

I am going to link them here in hopes I can draw attention to them (cause I can't set up a bounty yet).

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, in asking my questions.  Did I ask something that made completely no sense?  I really do need the help.  I am self taught and I can't figure this out.  I also did not want to make exact replicates of the posts I've very carefully typed up already, but I may have to do so until I get some sort of answer.

[Ordering Posts List By Taxonomy Terms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209870/ordering-posts-list-by-taxonomy-terms)

[Creating a sortable table of posts by taxonomies?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209383/creating-a-sortable-table-of-posts-by-taxonomies)

[Custom Post Type and Taxonomies Structures](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209346/custom-post-type-and-taxonomies-structures)

Thanks StackExchange and sorry.

Comment: You have no reason to be sorry. I admire your effort. I'll run through them.

Comment: You may be too far into your system but maybe upon saving your posts you also save your taxonomy ( such as Directors ) as `post_meta`. It's much **much** *much* easier to sort on `post_meta` than taxonomies. [WP_Query has an `orderby => 'meta_value'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) which would work nicely. I believe if you want to order posts alphabetically by Director ( terms ) then you would need to write custom SQL. [See this similar question and answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/69290/7355).

Comment: I would recommend to ask on [meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/) if you want some help about improving your questions. _This_ one doesn't quite make sense on main site.

Comment: if you want answers you need to make it easier for people to answer your questions. Narrow down the amount of information required in order to answer the question. I really don't need to know your website inside out to tell you how to order by a `custom_meta`. Could you please post the query arguments you are using now?